# Reselect - how to figure out which argument changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

> Selectors are efficient. A selector is not recomputed unless one of its arguments changes.

I'm trying to debug a selector that is being called more often than expected. Is there a way to log why a particular selector was recomputed (i. e. which argument changed)?

Example:

```
export const totalSelector = createSelector(
  [subtotalSelector, taxSelector]
  (subtotal, tax) => ({ total: someExpensiveCalculation(subtotal, tax) })
)
```

Now let's say that the return value of `totalSelector` is supplied to some component as a `result` prop via `mapStateToProps`. `why-did-you-render` reports unnecessary render due to changing reference (not value) of `result`. Therefore I know `totalSelector` must have been recomputed and we know from the docs that it only happens when of its inputs change (`subtotal` or `tax` in the example). How can I tell whether it was `subtotal` that triggered a change or `tax` or both?

For the purpose of this explanation let's assume both `subtotal` and `tax` are objects, so they are passed by reference.

Comment: You need to add more detail e.g. your selector code and model.

Comment: @BenSmith example and further explanation provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that helped me in my situation is to put a breakpoint at this [line](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect/blob/0dab037cdeef83b40de88d9bb114a77541092c58/src/defaultMemoize.ts#L107) so that you can clearly see the argument that is causing the recomputation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple drop-in replacement for `createSelector` which will log the first changed param value:

```
const createDebugSelector = createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize, {
  equalityCheck: (previousVal, currentVal) => {
    const rv = currentVal === previousVal;
    if (!rv) console.log('Selector param value changed', currentVal);
    return rv;
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check this tool out: https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Put it on the component (the one wrapped in connect) and it will tell you which props are deep equal but not shallow equal.

Comment: I'm using this tool, on the component level it does a great job. So I know that a particular selector got recomputed. What I want to know is why it was recomputed.

Comment: His blog posts actually have great descriptions of the problems and potential fixes:
https://medium.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render-mr-big-pure-react-component-part-2-common-fixing-scenarios-667bfdec2e0f. If you post the code of your selector I may be able to help more

Comment: example provided, it's not really about the selector implementation though.

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this to debug: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-faraday-jw99j.  Create a custom createSelector where you log out the values and if they are equal or not